# Identifying French Door Astragal Replacement Parts

Tags: doors

Wife and I just bought a house and I'm looking for replacement parts for the astragals on our French doors. Therma-Tru was only manufacturer marking on slide bolt. I reached out to them and provided pictures and they replied stating these are not their astragal/parts. I am unsure of the names of pieces.

I have searched and searched with no luck on AllAboutDoors, Strybuc etc. I have even reached out to their customer service with no replies after a week.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the parts I'm looking for:

[image]

White piece side view: (this piece slides into astragal and is some kind of weather stripping):

[image]

Brown piece side view: (this piece also slides into astragal and looks like a protection door piece for opposite door):

[image]

Close up of brown piece:

[image]

Second brown piece: (this piece goes inside of astragal in a slot):

[image]

Close up of second brown piece:

[image]

Slot on astragal that second brown piece fits into:

[image]

Comment: Google 'Pemco weatherstripping'. They probably make some of those, though you'll be stuck buying 40' at a time. And, a Pemco dealer might be able to help you with the rest.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I have looked all over at Pemco weatherstripping with no luck. I have emailed a few other companies to provide the pics in hopes of them identifying the pieces.